# Codeigniter : Pass result_set from row_array and result_array to view file

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I have a controller function which have two result_sets, one is the result_set from row_array(), second is the result_set coming from result_array(), as follows.

```
public function show_images($folderid)
{
$this->load->model('footer_model');
$data['footer'] = $this->footer_model->footer_list(); //result_set from row_array
$this->load->model('gallery_model');
$data['image_info']  = $this->gallery_model->get_allimages($folderid); //result_set from result_array
//print_r($data); exit();
$this->load->view('gallery/gallery_slides',$data); 
 }
```

The two result sets are passed to the view, which i am puzzled how to retrieve it. Is there a way to retrieve it. How should i do it in view file through `foreach` or through some other way?..

To be simple, the following is the result passed to the view:

```
Array ( 
      [footer] => 
       Array ( 
              [footer_id] => 1 
              [address1] => Wanderer,'The Refugee', 
              [address2] => XYX Compound, Observatory Road 
              [place] => Kodaikanal 
              [phone_no] => 2341929 
              [copyright_link] => www.megatrend.co.in 
              [email] => dbarunkumart@yahoo.co.in 
              ) 
      [image_info] => 
       Array ( 
             [0] => 
             Array ( 
             [file_name] => DSC00081.JPG 
             [folder_name] => foldername ) 
             [1] => 
             Array ( 
             [file_name] => DSC00082.JPG 
             [folder_name] => foldername ) 
             )
         )
```

Comment: In your view, the keys of the array will be treated as variable.
In your view, you can access footer values as `$footer`. Similarly `$image_info`

Comment: @DineshPatra, In  view, I can take using `echo $footer['address1']` , but `echo $image_info ` doesn't worked

Comment: $image_info[0]['file_name']   is not it working ?

Comment: ```$image_info``` is array so you cant echo'ed it.

Comment: @kishor10d, yes i should retrieve it .. how should i?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Dinesh mentioned, you can access the `$footer` directly and the `$image_info` in a loop.

Example of `$footer` in your view:

```
<footer>
    <?= $footer['address1'] ?>
    <?= $footer['address2'] ?>
</footer>
```

Example of `$image_info` in your view

```
<footer>
   <?php foreach($image_info as $img) { ?>
      <img src="YOUR_PATH/<?= $img['file_name']; ?>"/>
   <?php } ?>
</footer>
```

Comment: I modified the code which exactly meeting my code, and it worked great. It was as easy it is..!

Comment: Glad i could help. I miss-clicked the save button on your edit by mistake! You can re-edit and i will approve :)